# Flutter - User education about gestures(Swipes)

Tags: flutter, material-design, swipe

I want to show users that they can swipe left to go to next screen in flutter. Is there any widgets for that. I'm using gesture detector to catch the swipe action, but I don't know how to educate user about swipe? It's like the home screen action in Google Phones which jumps to swipe up to see the apps screen. Thank you in advance.(https://material.io/design/motion/#usage -- User Education).

Answer (score 1):

There is a showcase [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/showcaseview) you can use. If you want to add more dynamic hints, you can customize widgets and add some animations to make your own hints (eg. a finger image scrolling on screen).